# Flutter Stack doesn't make children overlap

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to put a horizontal line(currently `Divider` but could be changed as a `CustomPaint`) as a background of a `Row`. However, regardless of the order of children, the line always goes front of the `Row`. I can't figure out what's wrong. Here's the code.

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned.fill(
      child: const Divider(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Ink(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 32)
          ),
        ),
        Ink(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Icon(Icons.location_on, size: 32)
          ),
        ),
        Ink(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Icon(Icons.flag, size: 32)
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

and here's the result image.

[image]

Comment: remove Positioned.fill

Comment: @Z.Cajurao Not working, and broke the layout(line not being centered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Container` instead of `Ink`

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned.fill(
      child: const Divider(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 32)
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Icon(Icons.location_on, size: 32)
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Icon(Icons.flag, size: 32)
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, can I ask the reason?

Comment: According to this documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink-class.html, `Ink` is to give splashes and highlights to the underlying Material. `Container`, on the other hand, paints itself, rather than deferring to the nearest Material widget.

Comment: The <code>Ink</code> widget draws the given Decoration directly on the Material, in the same way that <code>InkWell</code> and <code>InkResponse</code> draw there. So as the <code>InkWell</code> draws above the child when an action is done, the <code>Ink</code> widget draws over the widgets...even if it is in a stack

Comment: @MichaelYuwono,  I do have the similar problem. Native android view always shows on top of other widget. It would be helpful if i get a suggestion for my issue. Issue link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72291539/flutter-stack-widget-always-shows-the-platformviewlink-android-widget-at-the-t